# Does it make sense to turn of compiler optimization for performance measurements?

Tags: performance-testing, hpc

In a few papers from my research area I just found a statement from the authors that disabling compiler optimizations completely makes a performance measurement of two codes fair.

I disagree, because:

1. Compiler optimizations are used in every code in production.
2. Optimizations will get rid of surplus temporary objects, fixed sized loops will be unrolled, etc, without impacting the correctness of the output, so why not code with these things in mind?
3. Of course, the algorithms should be developed with efficiency in mind where this is relevant, without exclusively relying on the compiler to make the code fast, but the compiler optimizations cannot harm, can they?

If it helps, I am asking for C++ codes for scientific computing.

When reporting performance measurements do you use compiler optimizations or not, and why? Any references to HPC literature would help. I have found [this great paper abot HPC measurements](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2807591.2807644), that states

> typically, one compares the effect of an optimization or system on
>   various applications

Say we have codes A and B. If code A is faster than code B in optimized mode (statistically), and slower without optimization, would you say that A is faster than B?

Comment: It makes no sense to turn off optimisation for performance measurement in HPC when comparing different codes.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: I also figured it makes no sense, but it would be great to find some kind of a reference that I can quote, besides common sense. :)

Comment: Quote me, go right ahead.  My earlier comment was not made solely on common sense, I have 15 years experience on HPC platforms, supercomputers, etc.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: I believe you, unfortunately, I'm involved in an academic discussion, so I'll need to find a reference, or similar. The thing is, this information seems to be so basic, I can't find a sentence on it anywhere. I've found some info in [Agner Fog's book](https://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf), in the section "Optimizations in the compiler", but no outright sentence "one should always compare compiler-optimzied code".

Comment: You'll struggle to find authoritative references telling you to put your socks on before you put your shoes on - sometimes common sense **is** the best guide !